# How to display performance in a react render function

Tags: reactjs

I have a react render function and I would like to print out how long it takes to run the function. My code stub is here. I'm using performance-now library and ES6+.

Now the last line I'm suppose to print out how long it took to run the render function, but nothing shows. If I just show the last line, then it works. But I want to show the performance in the top of the app and not on the bottom.

```
const start = now();
    const {list,load} = this.props; // eslint-disable-line
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <Helmet title="Experient Page"/>
      <h1>Experiment Page</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {load(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));}}>
       Click to reload.
      </button>
      <p id="result"></p>
      {
        list.map((foo) => {
          return <div>Hello, {foo}!</div>;
        })
      }
      {() => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Total time rendered is ' + (now() - start); // eslint-disable-line
      }}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Why are you passing a function as a child?

Comment: I though it would work easily. The original line was <p>Total time rendered is {(now() - start)}  and that would work fine, but it is on the bottom on the page. I would like to display that on top of the page, under the button.

Comment: Then why don't you just move it there? *"I though it would work easily."* What gave you the impression that you can pass a function as a child to a React component?

Comment: Because now() need to be computed at the end of the <div> but I want the answer to be at the beginning of the <div>.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about how JSX works. Your code is basically converted to `React.createElement('div', [ React.createElement(...), list.map(...), now() - start])`. It's just a function call. I.e. if you just want to to know how long it takes to map over the list, do that beforehand: `const items = list.map(...); return <div>{items}{now()-start}</div>;`. If you really want to measure rendering performance, use the React perf tools.

Comment: I see, I just want to have an easy way to display how long a render function takes and display it anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the React.js Perf API, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html).
Don't forget to use development's React bundle and not the production one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it's not showing for you but have you tried using componentDidMount() rather than inside of your render?

Also, React's performance tools do a great job detecting wasted renders:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html